# How to remove all namespaces from XML in PHP (tags and attributes)

Tags: php, xml, regex, xml-parsing, xml-namespaces

I've recently had serious grief from XML namespaces and dealing with them effectively in PHP. Here's a sample of the worst kind of culprit:

```
<dc:type xsi:type="TypeName" xsi:identifier="NN">Others</dc:type>
```

What I successfully managed to do using preg_replace was to "un-namespace" the tags (without breaking URLs) using:

```
$xml = preg_replace(
  '/<(\/?)([^:" ].*):([^>\/ ].*)(\/?)>/msiU',
  '<$1$2_$3$4>',
  $x->readOuterXML()
);

# <dc_type xsi:type="TypeName" xsi:identifier="NN">Others</dc_type>
```

What I couldn't do - through lack of regular expression wizardry - was convert all namespaced attributes into the same format. I managed to convert the first occurence, but don't know how to set a repeatable condition. I deleted the code because it didn't work (and I can't remember what I did), but the result was like this:

```
<dc_type xsi_type="TypeName" xsi:identifier="NN">Others</dc_type>
```

Whereas what would be beautiful is this:

```
<dc_type xsi_type="TypeName" xsi_identifier="NN">Others</dc_type>
```

Are there any regex masters out there who can help?

Comment: Are you using [PHP's `XMLReader` here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xmlreader.php)? I find it normally easier to re-write the XML by using the expat based parser, here is an answer that has an example how that (rudimentary) works at its end: [PHP change xmlns in XML file](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15193159/367456)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To rewrite a complete XML document like renaming element or attribute names as well as changing namespace related data like `xmlns` attributes, you can use the expat based xml parser extension:

- [PHP XML Parser](http://php.net/book.xml.php)

This works by parsing the file and change the output on the fly. The parser invokes callback functions (so called *handler*) that gets the data pre-parsed, for example the elements name in form of a string and the attributes in form of an array.

You then can change these values on the fly and output the (potentially changed) data.

Done this way you don't need to care about regular expressions any longer (which is non-trivial for proper XML parsing).

You can find some boilerplate code to get this started in [a previous answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15193159/367456).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I was avoiding using the XMLParser extension as it reads the whole file in one chunk (AFAIK). The files I've been dealing with are too big for the server to handle in one go. XMLReader allowed me to read the file and perform actions on the fly, but SimpleXML doesn't give you immediate access to namespaced tags or attributes, so I was looking to remove all namespacing before parsing the XML chunk with SimpleXML, hopefully giving me a complete array/object to work with in each iteration of a tag.

Comment: @BenArtiss: Then I have good news to you, the XMLParser does work on chunks of data, too. You can pass in buckets and for the last bucket you send a flag saying it's the last one.

Comment: Although I'm happy to use hakre's solution, it would still be nice to know how to achieve the repeated condition in preg_replace. If anybody knows how, it would certainly help for other regex things in the future.

Comment: @Ben Artiss: You mean you want to learn how to parse XML with regular epressions? Well, nobody stops you, here is a good introductory read: http://www.cs.sfu.ca/~cameron/REX.html :)

Answer (score 5):

I was looking for the same thing but I know better than to try using regular expressions against XML (search for just about any StackOverfow question about parsing XML/HTML with regex and read the whole answer to find out why. You'll know it when you see it)!

Here is the code I came up with:

```
<?php
// Some test XML
$xml = <<<XML
<root xmlns:a="bogus.a" xmlns:b="bogus.b">
    <a:first>
        <b:second>text</b:second>
    </a:first>
</root>
XML;

$sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$dom_sxe = dom_import_simplexml($sxe);

$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$dom_sxe = $dom->importNode($dom_sxe, true);
$dom_sxe = $dom->appendChild($dom_sxe);

$element = $dom->childNodes->item(0);

// See what the XML looks like before the transformation
echo "<pre>\n" . htmlspecialchars($dom->saveXML()) . "\n</pre>";
foreach ($sxe->getDocNamespaces() as $name => $uri) {
    $element->removeAttributeNS($uri, $name);
}
// See what the XML looks like after the transformation
echo "<pre>\n" . htmlspecialchars($dom->saveXML()) . "\n</pre>";
?>
```

Comment: Perfect. I'm writing a system that can use any XML from any source, so figuring out what to do with all the namespaces on the fly is a lot more work than I wanted to undertake (small chance it'll bite me in the future, but worth the risk for prototyping). One change: this code didn't work on nested namespaces; I switched `getDocNamespaces()` for `getNamespaces(true)` which resolved the problem. Wish I could give another upvote.